# How to retrieve many objects from .dat File using Java?

Tags: java, file, object

I have admin account which should be able to **add many users** to a .dat file. Then I want to retrieve all the objects from the .dat file into a list for further programming.

```
public class User implements Serializable { //get and set methods }
```

This is hwo I am writing each object to the .dat file

```
public void addNewUser() throws Exception {
    User newUser=new User();
    newUser.name="test";
    newUser.position="admin";

    FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream("Users.dat", true);
    ObjectOutputStream objectOutputFile = new ObjectOutputStream(outStream);

        // Write the object to the file. 
        objectOutputFile.writeObject(newUser);
        // Close the file.
        objectOutputFile.close();
}
```

How can retrieve all the objects from the .dat file into ArrayList??

```
public class displayUsers { **//what to do??** }
```

Comment: You are confusing others by writing one user object and asking for code reading a List<User>. Perhaps you can clarify this.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write the list object and read it as list. But since you're writing user objects individually, you can do something like this -

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Users.dat"));
Object object = null;
while ((object = ois.readObject()) != null) { 
    if (object instanceof User) {
        User user = (User) object;
        list.add(user);
    }
}
```

Of course, you would need to take care of exceptions (like EOFException).

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is bad practice to concatenate individual `ObjectOutputStream`s in a file without adding any lengths or delimiters. So better write all objects in one pass (and use `ObjectOutputStream.reset` in case your process is long-running and you fear memory leaks (otherwise ObjectOutputStream will keep a reference to every object it serialized before) or add them to a List and write it.

If you have to write it in multiple passes, I'd suggest to write the individual objects to a `ByteArrayOutputStream` first, and then use `DataOutputStream` to write the array prefixed by its length. That way, you can use `DataInputStream` to get out the individual byte arrays and use `ByteArrayInputStream` to deserialize them.

In case this does not work, you can try this solution (depending on the lookahead used by `ObjectInputStream`, this might not work for more complex objects with custom serialization formats, though, so use at your own risk):

```
public static void displayUsers() throws Exception {
    FileInputStream fiis = new FileInputStream("Users.dat");
    InputStream fis = new FilterInputStream(fiis) {
        @Override
        public void close() throws IOException {
            // ignore
        }
    };
    try {
        while (true) {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            User user = (User) in.readObject();
            in.close();
            System.out.println(user.name + "/" + user.position);
        }
    } catch (EOFException ex) {
        // done
    }
    fiis.close();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<User> listOfUser = new ArrayList<User>();
ObjectInputStream input = null;
try {
    while (true) {
      input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("Users.dat"));
      listOfUser.add(input.readObject());
    }
}
catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
finally {
   input.close();
}
```

Comment: More than one user, anyone?